# Adding Radio button to Calendar in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, calendar, radio-button

I'm trying to make a Calendar which can have radio buttons embedded in specific dates, which will be chosen by making a service call, but that's not a problem. I have had two approaches to it so far, one could be taking a datagrid, and making it a calendar, and then placing the radio button inside the cell using an item renderer. The second approach could be Extending the Calendar class, and adding radio buttons inside. Using the first approach, the problem is to fit the dates in the right order in the grid for any specific month. We could get to know the first day (Mon,Tue..) of the month but filling the grids correctly causes issues. I was wondering if someone ever tried doing this or if there could be a simpler approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which class were you thinking of Extending?  As far as I know Flex does not have a Calendar class.

You should be able to do this, relatively easy, using the Flextras Calendar ( http://www.flextras.com/?event=ProductHome&productID=15 ) and using a custom dayRenderer.

Let me know if I can answer any questions about that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following tutorial:
http://www.thetechlabs.com/tutorials/interfaces/create-a-dynamic-event-calendar-in-flex-builder-3-with-actionscript-30/

Wish it can help.

Comment: Yes I did, however, that tutorial is focused more towards using at as event based calendar, my primary concern is to be able to spawn, radio button inside dates of the calendar.